# WinJS: Save observable objects without backingData etc. to JSON

Tags: json, save, winjs, observable

what is the best way to save observable objects to JSON without _backingData etc.?
For example instead of:

```
[{"_backingData":{"name":"Test","hourlyRate":""},"name":"Test","hourlyRate":"","id":-1,"number":"","backingData":{"name":"Test","hourlyRate":""}}]
```

This should be saved:

```
[{"name":"Test","hourlyRate":"","id":-1,"number":""}]
```

This is my code to save the data:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(value.concat());
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.createFileAsync("customer.json", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting)
                .then(function (file) {
                    return Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeTextAsync(file, data);
                });
```

value is a WinJS.Binding.List().

Is there a simple solution to solve this "problem"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `WinJS.Binding.unwrap` over the individual elements in the array.